# Android Things and RXTX library

Tags: android, android-things, rxtx

There are a few libraries I use that use the RXTX library, but android things doesn't seem to work with it.

Im using the raspberry pi and try to initiate Uart for Fona, an Adafruit library

```
     Fona fona = new Fona();
    try {
        fona.open("UART0", 115200);
    } catch (FonaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fona.smsSend("0555555555", "Hello from FONA!");
    } catch (FonaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fona.close();
    } catch (FonaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I get the following error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.things.jar"
```

Here is my Manifest that I gave USE_PERIPHERAL_IO permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.SET_TIME" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.things.permission.USE_PERIPHERAL_IO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" />



<application>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.things" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <!-- Start automatically after boot and re-start if the app is terminated. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and my gradle that I added the android library to

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.www.fun"
    minSdkVersion 27
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
implementation files('libs/xbee-java-library-1.2.1.jar')
implementation files('libs/RXTXcomm-2.2pre2.jar')
}

dependencies {
implementation ('com.google.android.things:cloud-iot-core:1.0.0'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Lastly, I'm used OS version 1.0.3 for my build.

Is there anyway I can get this working

Comment: Any advantages of using RXTX library over `Android Things` [UART API](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/uart)?

Comment: There’s a number of fully featured libraries that use RXTX library. Xbee Java library is another good one.